# Assembly in Linux

Tags: linux, assembly

I'm reading a tutorial on building compilers.In the tutorial the compiler produces assembly 80X86 and I want to know if the programs made by this compiler would run in a Intel Celeron Linux.If not what kind of assembly the compiler should produce there?

Comment: I think you a accidentally the whole verb.

Comment: Processor and operating system are separate issues. To work on your target OS, the question is if the compiler or assembler produce the right executable or linking format.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to make sense of your question. If you are asking how to compile assembly code in Linux, http://asm.sourceforge.net/ seems to provide some information.

As for assemblers, there is [GAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler) and [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/).

Answer (score 1):

Celeron is x86. gcc will assemble things for you. (the -S option, I believe.)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, simply use nasm. Works perfectly here. Good luck.